Question about refrigerator troubleshooting when it only cools to 50º
What would cause a refrigerator to cool to only 50°F?
I have a 11 cubic foot Galanz refrigerator, model GLF11US2A16 which doesn't cool below 50°F. It has two different modes, refrigerator or freezer.

I have tried both refrigerator and freezer modes and it will not cool below 50°F.

What troubleshooting steps would you recommend?
Any suggestions on where could I source parts for this model?

I have tried to look up parts for Galanz online and I don't see any parts available. I tried https://www.galanzparts.com/search-parts but you have to know the part number. I am not sure if this site is legit.

Call the number listed on the label. It was manufactured all of 8 months ago, so it should be under some sort of warranty.

Given that one of the review's on home Depot's website is:

Evaporator Fan Issues
I bought one and it ran in freezer mode for about 7 months and then the evaporator fan went out so it was not properly cooling it. I had $400 of meat in it and so I had to run out that night and find a substitute for it so I wouldn’t loose all my meet. I contacted customer support and they were a little difficult but they ended up sending me a whole new unit instead of the $25 fan that went out. The second one had been running for 5 months and the fan is slowly dying on that one as well…

I would guess that your unit is defective.
Call the company and complain ASAP.

They are refunding me for the refrigerator (so they say) but I would like to try and salvage it instead of throwing it away and buying a new one.

@amrog Nice, after you get the new fridge then start taking the old one apart and assess which component failed. That component should have a part number which you can search for on the Internet. If that sounds like too much work then a repair person would likely charge $200-$400 to fix it for you. Good luck!

If it's a failed fan as in the review, a generic replacement might last longer than "the exact defectively designed part" (extrapolating considerably based on limited information.)

@Ecnerwal OP could very well have the same issue but I have no desire to teach OP how to become a fridge technician; that's their endeavor =)
